# Prove a conclusion of LDP: $\frac{1}{n}\log P(|\hat{S}_n|\geq\delta)\xrightarrow{n\xrightarrow{}\infty}-\frac{\delta^2}{2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

I plan to learn something about Large Deviation Principle (LDP). I am reading the book *Large Deviations Techniques and Applications* and immediately confused by a problem in the first page.

The original text is

> Note that
>
> $P(|\hat{S}_n|\geq\delta)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\delta\sqrt{n}}^{\delta\sqrt{n}}e^{-x^2/2}dx$
>
> therefore,
>
> $\frac{1}{n}\log P(|\hat{S}_n|\geq\delta)\xrightarrow{n\xrightarrow{}\infty}-\frac{\delta^2}{2}$

I have no idea how the results is gotten. The problem may be concluded as

Proof: For any $\delta$, $\frac{1}{n}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\delta\sqrt{n}}^{\delta\sqrt{n}}e^{-x^2/2}dx\right)\xrightarrow{n\xrightarrow{}\infty}-\frac{\delta^2}{2}$

Comment: Should that be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 n}}$?

Comment: @Michael: Thank you for your correction!